# How do I remove a button on a separate layout?

Tags: android, kotlin

I wrote my code so that when you click the plus button, it makes a new button on the main layout. You can then click the button and it'll go to the second layout page where there is a drop-down menu that gives the option to delete. However, I have no idea how to make it so that once you click the delete button it deletes that specific button on the main page (not all of the dynamically made buttons). Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

My `main.kt` code:

```
    package com.example.test

import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        showEditTextDialogue()
    }

    private fun showEditTextDialogue() {
        val btn = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn)
        btn.setOnClickListener{

            val inflator = layoutInflater
            val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout)
            val dialogLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_layout, null)
            val editText = dialogLayout.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_editText)
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            val newbutton = Button(this@MainActivity)
            val btnintent = Intent(this, Newbtn::class.java)
            val tst= Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "New quiz created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)


            newbutton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            newbutton.width=1010
            newbutton.height=300
            newbutton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            newbutton.translationX= 65F
            newbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"))
            newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#250A43"))

            with(builder) {
                setTitle("Title:")
                setPositiveButton("Ok"){dialog, which ->
                    layout.addView(newbutton)
                    newbutton.text = editText.text.toString()
                    tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,700)
                    tst.show()
                }
                setNegativeButton("Cancel"){dialog, which ->
                    Log.d("Main", "Negative button clicked")
                }
                setView(dialogLayout)
                show()
            }
            newbutton.setOnClickListener{
                val dialogLayout2 = inflator.inflate(R.layout.new_button_option, null)
                with(builder){
                    setTitle(newbutton.text)
                    setPositiveButton("Play"){dialog, which ->
                        startActivity(btnintent)
                    }
                    setNegativeButton("Edit"){dialog, which ->
                        startActivity(btnintent)
                    }
                    setView(dialogLayout2)
                    show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `delete.kt` code:

```
    package com.example.test

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast

class Newbtn : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newbtn)
    }
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.k_ari, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.item1 -> {
                startActivity(intent)
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some pictures for better understanding? You can't delete the button, but you can change it's visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I am not convince with Kotlin. I could tell you how to do it in java.

The program you are actually calling that's not removing/deleting button. It is changing visibility of that button.

In java

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In Kotlin

```
view.visibility = if (view.visibility == View.VISIBLE){
    View.INVISIBLE
} else{
    View.VISIBLE
}
```

I didn't write that Kotlin source code. I took it from internet or another page.
I think it is explaining that if view(`layout` where you can include `Button`) is visible than it will invisible. But, `GONE` is better than invisible cause, `GONE` hide the layout also. So, You have to try `GONE`.